# Hibernate oneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Есть класс с таким полем

```
class UserData
```

...

```
 @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_data_book",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="user_data_id",insertable = false,updatable = false,nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="favorites_id",insertable = false,updatable = false,nullable = false)
    )
    public List<Book> getFavorites() {
        return favorites;
    }
```

...

Со стороны клиента мне прилетает json объект данного класса, но только без этого поля. Я хочу обновить данный объект в бд, но чтобы поле List getFavorites() не обновлялось. На данный момент в линковочной таблице user_data_book удаляются все записи с id обновляемого объекта. Как сделать, чтобы таблица user_data_book не обновлялась??

Comment: Взять список книг из таблицы и закинуть его в setFavorites. После этого произвести обновление в базе.

Comment: Лишний запрос получится

Comment: Согласен, погуглив нашел вот такой [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674516/hibernate-dirty-checking-and-only-update-of-dirty-attributes). Думаю, подойдет.

Comment: @StasDorozhko По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.